# How to create a notification popup which is mouse transparent?

Tags: javafx

**Task**

I'd like to create a notification window which is mouse transparent to the stage and the desktop.

**Problem**

The popup doesn't have a mousetransparent functionality. When a popup is showing, you have to wait until it disappears in order to access the content behind it.

**Question**

Is it possible to create notification popups (or other windows) which have a click-through mechanism? It should work for popups over the stage and popups over the desktop.

**Code**

Here's example code which creates a notification when you click on the button. The popup disappears after 3 seconds. After that you can click the button again.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Notification extends Application {

    static double width = 800;
    static double height = 600;
    static int counter = 0;

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        this.stage = stage;

        // content area
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");

        // button which shows a popup
        Button notificationButton = new Button("Add Popup");
        notificationButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            addNotification("This is notification nr. " + (++counter));
        });

        root.getChildren().add(notificationButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private void addNotification(String message) {

        // create popup content
        Label messageLabel = new Label(message);

        final StackPane content = new StackPane();
        content.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgrey");
        content.setOpacity(0.5);
        content.setMouseTransparent(true);

        content.getChildren().addAll(messageLabel);

        // create popup and show it
        final Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.setX(stage.getX() + (stage.getScene().getWidth() - 200) / 2);
        popup.setY(stage.getY() + (stage.getScene().getHeight() - 200) / 2);
        popup.getContent().add(content);

        popup.show(stage.getScene().getWindow());

        // hide popup after 3 seconds
        Duration displayDuration = Duration.millis(3000);
        KeyFrame displayDurationKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(displayDuration);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(displayDurationKeyFrame);
        timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {
            popup.hide();
        });
        timeline.play();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. I have removed the initModality() because that's what blocked input events from being delivered to the other window. I also added the listener to prevent the new Stage from gaining focus at all.

```
final Stage popup = new Stage();
popup.setX(stage.getX() + (stage.getScene().getWidth() - 200) / 2);
popup.setY(stage.getY() + (stage.getScene().getHeight() - 200) / 2);
popup.setScene(new Scene(content));
popup.initOwner(stage);
popup.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        stage.requestFocus();
    }
});
popup.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
popup.setOpacity(0.5);
popup.show();
```

[javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work on Windows 7, Java 8u65. Same effect, the popup blocks. However, with a new stage there is another problem: When the user e. g. types while you show a popup, the new stage gets the focus. It should show only the notification, but the user should be able to continue typing.

Comment: Thank you, the focus works now, but the main problem remains. I still can't click the button until the popup disappears. Does this really work for you? What system and Java version are you using?

Comment: It's the same as your system. What happens is if a node on the parent stage is stationed directly behind the popup, mouse events do not get to that specific node. But the popup does not interrupt or prevent typing, or clicking as long as the popup is not directly above the specific Button or TextField you're trying to click or use.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly the problem I'm having. The code in the question is already capable of showing a notification while not stealing the focus. It's just a MCVE. You could add a TextArea and a PauseTransition with 3s, type in the TextArea and after the 3s the notification appears without stealing the focus. Problem is when someone e. g. tries to scroll. Nobody wants to click on a scrollbar and all of a sudden some popup appears which catches the click. I know, don't overlap it with the scrollbar, but I want a general solution. Even if I have to use JNI.